# How to connect Realm with watchOS and iOS app at the same time?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, watchkit, realm

So, there simple instructions on Realm website:

> Installation (Swift 2.1.1): 
>   ...
>   2) Go to your Xcode project’s “General”
>   settings. Drag RealmSwift.framework and Realm.framework from the
>   ios/swift-2.1.1/, watchos/, tvos/ or osx/swift-2.1.1/ directory to the
>   “Embedded Binaries” section. Make sure Copy items if needed is
>   selected and click Finish.

Basically, stating that we need to use different Realm libraries for developing apps for Watch and for iPhone.

Problem here, is that if I want to create watchOS app I need to import library specific to it. When at the same time I'm trying to import library for iOS, I get error from xCode (version 7.2.1):

> Multiple errors occurred while copying the files

Making it impossible to add both libraries at the same time.

My goal is to share data between Watch and iPhone like instructed in [this](https://realm.io/news/tutorial-sharing-data-between-watchkit-and-your-app/) article, but even there author is missing information on how to setup 2 different libraries.

Appreciate any help or advice. Thank you.

Comment: That article is out-of-date.  watchOS 1 let you use app groups to share data between watch and phone.  It is no longer supported or available in watchOS 2.

Comment: @PetahChristian can you point me to more current solution for sharing data then? Either for Realm or Core Data is fine! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of the article. With watchOS2 you'll need to either implement the WatchConnectivity framework or rely on iCloud. You might want to check out [this article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/117329/watchos-2-tutorial-part-4-watch-connectivity) on WCSession.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are having adding both the iOS Frameworks and the WatchKit's frameworks is the exact same one I had

I solved this by copying both folders [iOS] [watchkit] into my Xcode project's folder, then adding the respective libraries to their target's Embedded Binaries section.

In this way, you will not be literally copying the same-named items to the same location and it will not throw the error!

Comment: This did work for me too. In that case, the installation instructions on the docs seem wrong.